# Android, Gradle: How to refer to the 'android' block from a different grade file

Tags: android, maven, gradle

In addition to the Module build.gradle file, I have another file that handles other tasks.  Lets call it: file2.gradle

Here is the Module build.gradle

```
apply from: "file2.gradle"

android {
...
}
```

Here is the file2.gradle

```
...
task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs // <-- Error Here.
}

...
publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
           ...
           artifact(androidSourcesJar)
           ..
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, I get an error because it doesn't know about 'android'.  How to I refer to 'android' in the second file2.gradle file?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you apply the `android` plugin? You should refer to the `android` block after that, so maybe put `apply from:` at the end of your file?

Comment: I wasn't aware that you can put apply from afterwards.  I always see it on top.  Does it matter?

Comment: I think when you use `apply plugin: "plugin-id"` the plugin is only applied after that (which means the `android` block isn't registered before applying the `com.android.application` plugin). So if you apply your other file before applying the plugin, it won't work.